# Segfault in fgets

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX_N 10000
#define MAX_D 5000
int main(){
        char* n = malloc(MAX_D);
        fgets(n,MAX_D,0);
        printf("\n n : %s \n",n);
        return 0;
}
```

The above program results in segmentation fault. Couldn't identify the root cause.

Comment: could it be fgets(,,0) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* fgets(char* str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

The third parameter of `fgets` is a `FILE *`, not a (POSIX) file descriptor, passing `0` is taken as a null pointer. Change

```
fgets(n, MAX_D, 0);
```

to:

```
fgets(n, MAX_D, stdin);
```

Comment: I will second that :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for fgets is
`fgets(char* str, int num, FILE * stream);`.

You've used `fgets(n,MAX_D,0);`

Change the third argument to either `stdin` (standard input - keyboard) or point it to some file.

Probably you were looking for `fgets(n,MAX_D,stdin);`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question is already answered.
Here is another way of doing it.

Since `fgets()` expects third-argument to be type `FILE *`.
An `int` File decsriptor can be converted to `FILE *` using `fdopen()`

Since `0` file descriptor corresponds to `stdin`, you can use the below.

```
fgets(n, MAX_D, 0);                 /* Incorrect */

fgets(n, MAX_D, stdin);             /* Correct */
fgets(n, MAX_D, fdopen(0, "r"));    /* Also Correct */
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try that code

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<malloc.h>
     #define MAX_N 10000
     #define MAX_D 5000
     int main()
    {
         char *n = malloc(MAX_D);
         fgets(n,MAX_D,stdin);     /* 0 means null */

        printf("\n n : %s \n",n);
       return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`

That's why, after calling `malloc()` family, always check for the success. Put a `NULL` check before using the pointer in `fgets()`.

Also, you need to use a `FILE *` as the 3rd argument in `fgets()`. Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) here. In

```
fgets(n,MAX_D,0);
```

Change `0` to `stdin` to read from standard input.

Comment: no, it is because gets don't add any chars in `n` string where user print it.